# Boostrap css and JS not behaving as expected with Play framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scala, playframework, twitter-bootstrap-3, playframework-2.3

I have create one Play and scala application and I was using boostrap css and js in my play template. I have noticed some strange behavior with my template.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css")">
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I was using css and js as above my page is not rendered as expected and it seems css is not applying correctly.

When I used CDN url page was rendering correctly.

Why it is not working with local downloaded css and js?

Comment: Difficult to answer if we don't know what routes you have defined, what is your directory structure, etc.

Comment: I have put bootsrap css and js both in public javascript and stylesheet folder as play framework recommended.

Comment: Just check my answer and/or duplicated question for the solution, if it's described unclear ask a question in comment  I'll try to describe better ;)

Answer (score 1):

You *exploded* the original Bootstrap to the Play's `stylesheets` and `javascripts` folders, didn't you ? **that's wrong**.

You can not divide it to other order - just unzip it somewhere and then include its parts from proper locations.

[@see: The same problem answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27091806/1066240)

Note that other JS libs will behave the same, just when you're moving their parts to other folders you are just braking internal relations.

Note 2: Play creates these folders, but do not enforce you to use them, you can rename them, move to subfolder or even delete and use any other one. It's just important to choose proper path in your template.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a play user but have you tried escaping the link tag? ie use "/>" at the end ? If that dose not help you could probably also try this syntax href='@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css")' or the other way around href="@routes.Assets.at('stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css')"

Comment: after wrapped with single quote it is giving Compilation error.

Comment: As I said I don't know plays template syntax but I found this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@{'/public/stylesheets/main.css'}" /> at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/templates so ending the link tag with "/>" and using single quote in href + starting the path with "/" could be something to try

Comment: Thanks @karma4u101 for link, but the example you have provided is using Groovy templete which was in Play old version. Now play using scala based own template engine.

Comment: ah yes I noticed, this maybe helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226267/css-in-play-framework-2-0-3